# CSS reset with presentational and deprecated tags

Tags: css, w3c, web-standards

Why does Eric Meyer have not advisable, presentational, deprecated, and non-semantic tags in his [css reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)? (I.e. applet, iframe, big, s, small, strike.)

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td 
{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
  font-weight: inherit;
  font-style: inherit;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because people still use them, unfortunately. There's nothing invalid about referencing deprecated elements in your stylesheet. It's invalid to actually use them in your markup. Meyer's reset is to fix the way your elements render, not to fix which elements you choose to use to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

It's a "just in case" addition to the reset. He has actually advised in the past not to use deprecated tags.

If you're following Standards gurus like Meyer, Cederholm, Collison, et. al., then you probably should already know NOT to use them anyway.